# Custom Alert in a TableView shows through?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, tableview, uialertview

Not sure how to start this thread as I've not seen this happen before?

Loading...

[image]

Before Search...

[image]

After Search...

[image]

I have a TableView with a custom loading Alert, when I added a SearchBar the custom loading Alert shows the lines from the TableView, has anybody seen this before, any ideas on how to fix?

Thanks guys.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)

{
    return [self.searchResults count];
}
else
{
    return [self.itemsToDisplay count];    }
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

for (MWFeedItem* item in itemsToDisplay) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [[item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText]   compare:searchText
                                           options:    (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {

        [self.searchResults addObject:item];

    }
}       
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{    
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar   scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: the table appear in your image for search result ???

Comment: I've added a few more images, does that help?

Comment: so it show up without u do anything ??? in normal mode ??

Comment: plz. post the code u use it for searchBar ??

Comment: Yes if I take out the search bar it looks fine. I will post the code now.

Comment: OK there is no problem in this one but where/when u show your custom alert ??

Comment: Here's the full code for that controller... http://snippi.com/s/cg4u4bb

Answer (score 0):

for this you can add following code

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicatoriew];
[self.view sendSubviewToFront:tableView];
```

this will set activity indicator position above the table view..
Good luck... :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `[super viewDidLoad]` twice?

```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
> 
>     [super viewDidLoad];
> 
>     // show in the status bar that network activity is starting
>     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
>     [[LoadingHUD loadingHUD] showInView:self.view];
```

---

Referring to your [file](http://snippi.com/s/cg4u4bb). Remove lines 37 & 38:

```
>     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
>     [super viewDidLoad];
```